# Upgrade kernel driver to the latest kernel RC version

Tags: drivers, upgrade, kernel

I've found out that Linux Kernel released a patch for the driver of my Wireless chipset by January 2022 in one of the latest kernel versions that is not supported by my current kernel (Ubuntu Focal).

I'm not willing to update the distribution, but just this driver with this patch.

Which are the options I have to make this happen?

I'm currently a subaverage Linux user because I've parked this OS for a while, and I'm trying to return. Please, don't be too generic on the steps because I'm currently unaware, for example, on how to recompile a Linux Kernel (I would be able to do such in case its needed, but I need to be spoonfed a little to make this happen)

Comment: Your question should link to how you "found out". A link to a specific kernel patch or release and/or the wireless chipset would be even better, so take a few minutes and try to find those specifics. While you are at it, also add your current kernel to the Question (`uname -r`). [How to edit your Question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1432065/edit)

Comment: Also add the version of Ubuntu to your question.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to move forward the kernel version by simply installing another distro-kernel like Liquorix.

This was the kind of answer I was looking for.

Fast and effective. Took my time to figure this out.